# Understanding a negative sentence

Tags: sentence, negation

“I don’t like anything that’s not expensive” 
Can anyone explain what this means? Do they only like expensive things or they don’t?

Comment: Double negatives are culturally relative, so any answer may be right or wrong depending on culture. In some (English speaking) cultures, a double negative is an emphatic negative ("I'm sure I don't know nothing at all") but in most (English speaking) cultures, the negatives cancel out.

Comment: I don't think the sentence of interest contains a double negative.  Yes, it contains two negatives but they apply to different parts of the sentence.

Comment: Remove the negatives from the sentence and the gist is similar - *I like anything that’s expensive*.  Note, however, that the meaning is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the speaker only likes things which are expensive.  The sentence is syntactically acceptable and entirely clear.  Perhaps, to make it clearer to yourself you could replace *not expensive* with *cheap* and see how that works.

Comment: As I said on a earlier deleted answer, the sentence only states that they don't like cheap things. Without further information you cannot be sure that "the speaker only likes things which are expensive" - they might dislike expensive things as well.

Comment: @KillingTime That is strictly true, but nit-picky. The intent of a typical speaker saying this would be to discriminate between what they like and what they don't like. If they didn't like anything, they'd say that instead.

Comment: @DMac They could dislike cheap things and be *ambivalent* about expensive things. Not disliking something doesn't necessarily mean liking it. And I think it's essential to be *nit-picky* in this case, since the question is asking for us to analyze it. The intent behind this statement, to me, has nothing to do with discriminating between two things. It's just a simple statement of dislike, Nothing is being said about anything else.